# Is there a way to have conditional "add" events in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js for my web app and it works semi-well so far. The problem is that sometimes I need to add items to the collection and have them go to the top of the page, and other times to the bottom. Sometimes I need them to animate, sometimes not. Is there a way to do this cleanly with backbone.js? Passing arguments to the "add" event would be a good way (for example "prepend: true"), but this doesn't seem to be an option...

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extend Backbone.Collection and override the add function:

```
PositionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
  add: function( model, options ){
    // do your stuff
    // call the real add
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.call(this, model);
  }
});
```

Only thing to keep in mind is that if you prepend, append you might want to copy Backbone.Collection.add altogether and play with it.

You could also rely on the collection sorting. Add your position and animation attribute to the model, sort on the position and listen to "add" events on the collection to animate it correctly.

Comment: What Julien said...( he seems to be a backbone.js guru here)

Comment: Thank you, that's elegant and clean.

Comment: Hmm, something odd's happening. If I do this (I just add it in the collection declaration, so it's Backbone.Collection.extend({model: MyModel, add: <your code>});, I get "this.model.get is not a function" when I try to run it (that error is in the View's render() method). I've decided to set some instance variables in the collection to act as flags for now, and that works fine, although it's unclean.

Comment: A general tip for people looking at this page: Rather than overriding the built in add method, you should try adding a bind to the "add" event within the model/collection. It's easier than dealing with Javascript's method of calling parent methods. This assumes you don't want to prevent the default behavior.

Comment: Dave, does the collection's add event get fired first/before any other views that may be listening to that collections add event? If this is dependent behavior, I think the "accepted" answer may be the only way. Although I'm not sure.